# Can I access my AWS SES email from a web browser?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

SES runs on an exchange server. How can I access my mail using the web? I have searched AWS docs with no results.

Answer (score 0):

SES is a "hosted" service provided by AWS. It doesn't run on Exchange Server. It's also not a "mail server" like GMail and can't be used for viewing your e-mail messages. Although you can use Amazon SES mailbox simulator to "capture" test emails sent with SES: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/mailbox-simulator.html

Answer (score 0):

You can't. From [SES page](https://aws.amazon.com/ses/):

> **Receiving Email**
>
> You can use Amazon SES to receive messages and deliver them to an
>   Amazon S3 bucket, call your custom code via an AWS Lambda function, or
>   publish notifications to Amazon SNS.

SES is not intended as a full featured email client for humans, but as a cost effective way for your application to use/integrate emails.